# Python 2.7 bottle web

Tags: python-2.7, bottle

I’m trying to figure out how to rename an existing text file when I change the title of the text file. If I change the title now, it’s going to create a new text file with the new title. The "old text file" that I wanted to save with a new name still exists but with the orginal name. So i got two files with the same content.

I’m creating new articles (text files) through @route('/update/', method='POST') in my ”edit templet” where title=title, text=text. Let’s say after I have created a new article with the name(title) = ”Key” and wrote a bit in that text file. Then If I want to edit/change my ”Key” article I click on that article and present the article in @route('/wiki/',)def show_article(article):. title = article, text = text)

In this template I can change my ”Key” name(title) to ”Lock”. I’m still using the same form @route('/update/', method='POST') to post my changes. 
Here is the problem, it creates a new text file instead of renaming the ”Key” article to ”Lock”.

How can I change the @route('/update/', method='POST') to make it realise that I’m working with an already existing text file and only wants to rename that file. 
I have tried to use two different method=’POST’ but only gets method not allowed error all the time.

```
        from bottle import route, run, template, request, static_file
        from os import listdir
        import sys
        host='localhost'

        @route('/static/<filname>')

        def serce_static(filname):
            return static_file(filname, root="static")

        @route("/")
        def list_articles():
            files = listdir("wiki")
            articles = []

            for i in files:
                lista = i.split('.')
                word = lista[0]
                lista1 = word.split('/')
                articles.append(lista1[0])

            return template("index", articles=articles)


       @route('/wiki/<article>',)
        def show_article(article):
            wikifile = open('wiki/' + article + '.txt', 'r')
            text = wikifile.read()
            wikifile.close()

            return template('page', title = article, text = text)


        @route('/edit/')
        def edit_form(): 

            return template('edit')

        @route('/update/', method='POST')
        def update_article():

            title = request.forms.title
            text = request.forms.text
            tx = open('wiki/' + title + '.txt', 'w')
            tx.write(text)
            tx.close()

            return template('thanks', title=title, text=text)

        run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

Comment: did you see my answer, did it work?

Comment: I can’t get it to work. Because I cant grab the title of the text file that I want to change.

Comment: That makes no sense. How do you plan to operate on something if you don't know its name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.replace('old_name', 'new_name')`:

```
import os
...
tx = open('wiki/' + title + '.txt', 'w')
tx.write(text)
os.replace(tx.name, 'name_you_want.txt') # use os.replace()
tx.close()
```